# Change horizontal axis labels in XY Scatter chart with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have plotted a XY Scatter plot with VBA code. But I'm unable to change the horizontal axis labels. Can the horizontal axis labels be changed to text? If yes, how can I change it with arrays.

This is the XY Scatter chart I have created with VBA:[XY Scatter chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzVCn.png)

I would like to change the horizontal labels from 1,2,3,4 (as marked in the chart) to A,B,C,D using arrays. Thank you very much!

Edit:
My data table:
[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID9ly.png)

VBA macro code:

```
Sub plot_test3()

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i, j, c, m, n, a, lrow As Long
Dim frist_code, frist_value, frist_name, frist_date As Variant
Dim xychart As Chart

Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet3")

i = 1: j = 1: a = 1: k = 1: p = 2
c = 4: lrow = 6: m = 2: n = 2

ws2.Activate

ReDim frist_code(1 To lrow - 1)
ReDim frist_value(1 To lrow - 1)
ReDim frist_name(0)
ReDim frist_date(1 To lrow - 1)


Set xychart = ws2.Shapes.AddChart2(Left:=0, Top:=0, Width:=400, Height:=300).Chart

For j = 1 To c
    For i = 1 To lrow - 1
            frist_value(i) = ws2.Cells(m, n)
            frist_code(i) = k
            frist_name(0) = ws2.Cells(1, n)
            frist_date(i) = ws2.Cells(m, 1).Value2
        m = m + 1
    Next i
    
    
    xychart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    xychart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    With xychart.SeriesCollection(a)
        .Name = frist_name(0)
        .Values = frist_value
        .XValues = frist_code
        .MarkerSize = 15
        .MarkerStyle = 2
    End With
a = a + 1
n = n + 1
m = 2
k = k + 1
Next j

xychart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlLow
xychart.SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)

End Sub
```

Comment: I can share my VBA code if required

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because idea behind XY plot is to have a continuous X axis to use.

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ Agreed. But I think it should be possible with Line markers chart type. I have tried to plot the same chart with xlLineMarkers. But not able to generate the same chart :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XY Scatter is not adequate to such. XY expects continuous values over X axis and, as so, isn't compatible with named values.

To achieve desired labels, a discrete type chart must be used, like Line.

But for such, you can't have multiple values in same X value. You may:

1. consider using transposed data:
   [image: like this]
2. if color grouping required, using a serie by each point and then format every serie as required:
   [image]

EDIT: Code for 2nd option:

Following code will produce desired chart. Note chart isn't interactive, ie, changing values in spreadsheet won't change chart!

```
Sub Plot_Chart()
    Dim v(), r As Long, c As Long
    
    'Create and use chart
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlLineMarkers).Chart
    
        'Clear all series and legend
        While .SeriesCollection.Count
            .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        Wend
        .Legend.Delete
        
        'Iterate through rows and columns of data
        For r = 2 To Selection.Rows.Count
            For c = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
                            
                'Create series and use it
                With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries 'chart.SeriesCollection
            
                    'Create data with single valid point
                    ReDim v(1 To Selection.Columns.Count)
                    v(c) = Selection(r, c)
                    .Values = v
                    
                End With
            Next
        Next
        
        'Set and format X-Axis
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Selection.Rows(1).Value
        With .Axes(xlCategory)
            .MajorTickMark = xlNone
            .TickLabelPosition = xlLow
        End With
        
        
        'Format series
        For c = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
            .SeriesCollection(c).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleDiamond
            .SeriesCollection(c).MarkerSize = 7
            Set dbg = .SeriesCollection(c).Format.Fill
            .SeriesCollection(c).Format.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = (c - 1) Mod Selection.Columns.Count + 5
            .SeriesCollection(c).Format.Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = (c - 1) Mod Selection.Columns.Count + 5
        Next
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Your 1st plot is not suitable for me. However, your 2nd plot could be suitable for my data table. I will try to use your solution and check if I can solve my issue. Could you please share your macro code for the 2nd plot? It would be really helpful :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code and comments were really helpful!